# Copy Data to a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer

```
uint8_t *dataPtr
```

and I want to loop incrementing the pointer by one, copying bytes in one by one as they arrive from hardware.

My issue is how to copy data into the memory location of that pointer. Sounds so simple but I'm at a loss.

E.g.

```
uint8_t *dataPtr = (uint8_t*) data;
uint8_t tempData = 0;

for (uint8_t byteCnt = 0; byteCnt < noOfDataBytes; byteCnt++)
{

    // TODO: Get tempData

    dataPtr = tempData;     // How to copy tempData into the location of dataPtr.

    dataPtr++;

}
```

Comment: `dataPtr = tempData;` should be `*dataPtr = tempData;` (assuming that `data` is an allocated buffer).

Comment: `dataPtr` is a pointer to an `uint8_t` value. To get the value it points to you must *dereference* the pointer. Usually using the unary `*` operator, as in `*dataPtr`. This should be covered in any decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: You really need to provide a lot more detail - including your actual code.  *How* does data "arrive from hardware"?  How is that data consumed?  That's all important.

Comment: If you didn't get type mismatch compiler warning from `dataPtr = tempData;`, then you should check your compilation settings to make sure relevant warnings are enabled.

Comment: Regarding `for (uint8_t byteCnt = 0; ...` In general, don't use such a type for iteration unless you have severe constraints.

Comment: You need to tell us what `data` is in this line: `uint8_t *dataPtr = (uint8_t*) data;`

Comment: You probably don't need to use the temporary variable `dataPtr`. Instead use `data` and array indexing instead, like `data[byteCnt] = tempData;`

Comment: Also in case `data` is something like a hardware register/buffer or DMA buffer, access has to be done with a `volatile` qualified pointer.

Comment: @user694733 Rather, if you don't get any diagnostic message from that line, you should switch out the current junk compiler to a conforming C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

Looks so obvious now and I had already tried *dataPtr before posting. I had another issue that prevented that working before which caused the confusion.

What's wrong with the type

for (uint8_t byteCnt = 0; ...

Comment: Use the natural size `int` there. The iterator has no connection with the data type.